# Is there any solution to make my Flare Button work properly? Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart, flare

Basically, I have a button that I made in Flare and it should make an animation then I tap it! It works well but the animation starts everytime I tap anywhere within my app and not only the button.
Is there any way I can make animation only when I click in the Button Area? I`m using GestureDetector to handle tapping.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBjmz.jpg

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';  
import 'package:vibrate/vibrate.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home: InvalidButton(),
));

class InvalidButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InvalidButtonState createState() => _InvalidButtonState();
}

class _InvalidButtonState extends State<InvalidButton> {
  var _type = FeedbackType.heavy;
  final FlareControls controls = FlareControls();
  void _playAnimation(){
    controls.play('invalid');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink[50],
      body: Container(
        child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _playAnimation();
            Vibrate.feedback(_type);
          });
        },
        child: FlareActor(
          'assets/invalid_button.flr',
          animation: 'invalid',
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          controller: controls,
          ),
      ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I`m a newbie so will be glad to any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have space around the button in the Rive editor ? If so, go in design mode, click Artboard and then "fit contents". That should remove the extra space. Then, wrap your FlareActor with a SizedBox and set its size, like so :

```
SizedBox(
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  child: FlareActor(),
)
```

That should do it.